# Python selenium wait until button clickable

Tags: python, selenium

I have a python selenium code that upload a local video and click the button, the button can be clicked when video successfully uploaded so I try with `EC.element_to_be_clickable` and `EC.visibility_of_element_located` and when the button is clickable print a simple message, but always I got the message before video upload complete.
this is my code :

```
file_uploader = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_input')
file_uploader.send_keys(myvideo_file)
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'button_xpath')))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'button_xpath')))
        break
    except:
        pass
print("Button ready to be clicked!")
```

Comment: Does `button_xpath` XPath locator is unique?

Comment: yes it's unique

Comment: Why do you use `try-except` here? The timeout period is long enough. It should work without it.

Comment: it just to handle if any error happen to avoid break script code

Comment: No, it makes your code wrong. Can you remove it and see if errors thrown? If yes - what error?

Comment: There is no error

Comment: OK. Maybe that button indeed appears while uploading is still continuing?

Comment: the button is appear but you can't click it until the upload complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `get_attribute` of button.

If button is not clickable like `<button type="button" class="btn-post primary disabled">Post</button>`, then waiting until **disabled** disapeared in class name like `<button type="button" class="btn-post primary">Post</button>`

```
file_uploader = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_input')
file_uploader.send_keys(myvideo_file)

while True:
    # I insert finding element inside while loop because some sites delete existing elements and create new ones.
    # In this case, even if the deleted element and new one's xpath are the same, StaleElementException occurs.
    class_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_input').get_attribute('class')

    if 'disabled' not in class_name:
        break

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: this is the button element
```<button type="button" class="jsx-2205086601 button btn-post primary disabled">Post</button>```

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama I edit code based on button tag. Test with edited code

Comment: this is website https://www.tiktok.com/upload?lang=en
when the button is ready the disabled attribute disappear
```<button type="button" class="jsx-2205086601 button btn-post primary">Post</button>```

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama Then edited code will be done as your intent. Test and tell me it works or not

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama Test with the code I wrote in my answer.

Comment: working with this
```if
"disabled" in driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_input').get_attribute('class'):
#do```
thank you

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama : if it was helpful, try to accept the answer so it will be beneficial for others as well in future.

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama Maybe be `not in` is correct. Anyway glad to help you